# Why use the student's t-test rather than z-score?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, t-distribution

Suppose we are given IID r.v's $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ that are not necessarily normally distributed. Mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ are unknown and we want to construct a confidence interval for $\mu$.

We can compute the empirical mean and Bessel corrected variance $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2$.

The central limit theorem yields that $\sqrt{n} \cdot (\overline{X} - \mu)$ converges in distribution to $N(0, \sigma)$.

Also, since $S^2$ converges to $\sigma^2$, Slutsky's theorem yields that

$\frac{\overline{X} - \mu}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal, $N(0, 1)$ and using this we can construct confidence intervals.

Sometimes instead it is stated that for smaller samples we may use that $\frac{\overline{X} - \mu}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}}$ is approximately distributed as Student's $t$ with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

I suppose the reasoning goes something like the following.

The Student's $t$ with $n-1$ degrees of freedom arises as a quotient of $Z \sim N(0, 1)$ and $\sqrt{\frac{V}{n-1}}$ where $V \sim \chi^2 (n-1)$ and furthermore $Z$ and $V$ are independent.

Now I suppose one can prove that for large samples (how large?!) $S^2$ is close to distributed as $\sigma^2 \cdot \frac{\chi^2 (n-1)}{n-1}$.

Also $\overline{X} - \mu$ is close to distributed (again, for samples of reasonable size) as $N(0, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})$, so the quotient should be close to distributed as

$\frac{N(0, 1)}{\sqrt{\frac{\chi^2 (n-1)}{n-1}}}$ which is by definition Student's $t$.

We skated over here that the sample mean and Bessel-corrected sample variance are independent for normal IID-samples, but I suppose this is again only "approximately" true for non-normal samples and, yet again, is likely to put requirements on the sample size.

**All in all my feeling is that whilst it's stated that the Student's $t$-version should be more accurate for small samples, the fact that that very distribution is representative is in turn dependent on the sample size not being too small.**

If anyone could provide a more solid argument for why I should resort to Student's $t$ for small samples, I'd be happy.

Comment: [Student's original paper](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=student+1908+the+probable+error+of+a+mean) would be a good place to start.